# store 1d array from text file java

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

Am I reading the following input correctly?

Here is my code so far:

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        line = line.substring(line.indexOf('[')+1, line.indexOf(']'));
        String[] parts = line.split(",");

        for (int i = 0; i< parts.length; i++) {                               
            rangeNo[i]= Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);

            System.out.println("{" + rangeNo[i] + "}"); 
    }
  }
```

and this is my input

```
 [2,9], [3,11]
```

Also, when I try to print the value of rangeNo[3] it return 0 instead of 3

can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Why don't you run your code and see, if it is doing what you intend it to do?

Comment: There are only two items between the first `[` and the first `]`. So there is only going to be a meaningful number in `rangeNo[0]` and `rangeNo[1]`. What is `range` and what do you expect to see in its 4th element (index 3)?

Comment: why is your input looks more like 2D?

Comment: Without telling us what you are expecting it to do, there is no way we can really answer this question. It needs to be clarified.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I'm trying to record my input to a one d array and print it out to check the recorded array. Also excuse my typo, its suppose to be rangeNo[3]. Appreciate all the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you expect `[2,9], [3,11]` to be in `one` line or `two` separate lines?

If its supposed to be `one line` then you might want to try something like this

```
    Integer rangeNo[] = new Integer[10];
    String line = "[2,9], [3,11]";
    line = line.replace('[', ' ');
    line = line.replace(']', ' ');
    String[] parts = line.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        rangeNo[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i].trim());
        System.out.println("{" + rangeNo[i] + "}");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is exactly what I'm trying to do@jigar surana

Answer (score 0):

when you check here

```
line = line.substring(line.indexOf('[')+1, line.indexOf(']'));
```

it's matching first condition. i.e works fine for `[2,9]` not after that thus only `2` and `9` are getting stored here.

```
String[] parts = line.split(",");
```

so

```
parts[0]=2
parts[1]=9
parts[2]=0
```